# MassTransit Saga saves late with NHibernateSagaRepository (Starbucks example)

Tags: nhibernate, masstransit

I have converted the Starbucks example to use RabbitMQ and NHibernate.. However, there is a bug/challenge/issue with the DrinkPreparationSaga and when it actually gets saved to the database vs. when the PaymentCompleteMessage gets submitted.

How the code works (out of the box, this isn't anything I changed)... The new instance of the saga isn't saved to the database until AFTER the Initial state completes and it transitions to its next state.

The problem is that in the sample Starbucks application the DrinkPreparationSaga starts off with a very slow method that prints out coffee making sounds once every 1 a second 10 times..

So there is 10 seconds between when the Saga is actually created and when its saved to the database.. The bigger problem with that is, that any other messages that are destined to that instances of the saga (by CorrolationId) are thrown in the error queue because the Saga doesn't exist.

Shouldn't the NHibernateSagaRepository immediately save the new Saga Instance, then run the workflow, then update the saga post workflow?  I can't seem to think of another way to make the example work, but that would require a decent bit of reorganizing in the NHibernateSagaRepository.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason sagas are not saved before processing the message is that some members of the saga may not be nullable (or allow nulls) and they are not set before the initial saga message is processed.

And you're correct. Take a look at the Riktig sample (http://github.com/phatboyg/Riktig) to see how the Automatonymous sagas are used and how the correlation of another service (in this case, the image retrieval service) is used. Sagas should not actually perform work, but coordinate the state of a transaction. The earlier Starbucks example was a naive implementation that we built one morning in Austin. It is long overdue for an update (for more reasons, including that it still uses Magnum state machines, which are soon deprecated in favor of Automatonymous).